# CSS: How to make input fill rest of line, with a button on the right?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/0hr4m9y6/

I have a select dropdown + a text input field that both belong in one div so that I can have a border around the 2 things.. On the absolute right of this div should be a button that says "Search" (without a border)

I'm having issues putting all 3 (select, text input, search) all on the same line with the input stretching out from next to the select dropdown all the way to the right next to the Search button.

HTML

```
    <div class="blah">
        <div class="lineContainer">
            <div class="left">
                <select>
                    <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" id="text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Search">

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .lineContainer {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #000
    }
    .lineContainer div {
        height: 30px
    } 
    .left {
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid #000
    }
    .right {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #ccc
    }

    #text {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .blah {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

If you look at the fiddle, you'll notice I almost have it, but the input doesn't stretch to the width of the screen/window. I want it to stretch all the way, with Search being the rightmost thing on the line.

Comment: The only way to do this perfectly is with JavaScript. Otherwise you need to define some widths and let the let the input field fill in the rest.

Comment: * The only widely supported way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/0hr4m9y6/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="blah">
<div class="lineContainer">
    <div class="left">
        <select>
            <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" id="text">
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

CSS:

```
</div>
.lineContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.lineContainer div {
    height: 30px
} 
.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}
.right {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc
}

#text {
    width: 100%;
}

.blah {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.lineContainer {
    flex: 1;
}
```

The above solution uses flexbox. It's easier to use, but compatible with only IE10+. If you want IE compatibility, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/0hr4m9y6/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="blah">
<div class="lineContainer">
    <div class="left">
        <select>
            <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" id="text">
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Search">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lineContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.lineContainer div {
    height: 30px
} 
.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}
.right {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc
}

#text {
    width: 100%;
}

.blah {
    width: 100%;
}
.lineContainer {
    width:90%;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    width:9%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

NOTE: You can set `width:10%;` to the submit button, just give it a `box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an adjusted version that uses absolute positioning to make the input fill the full horizontal width between the dropdown and the submit button: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/0hr4m9y6/2/

```css
.blah {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.lineContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px;
    height: 24px; /* plus 6 for the top & bottom padding */
    width: 100px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px;
    left: 108px;
    right: 5px;
}
input[type='submit'] {
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    top: 3px;
}
#text {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blah">
    <div class="lineContainer">
        <div class="left">
            <select>
                <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input type="text" id="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap you can do this, pretty simple.
input or select will fill the available space, tried the other ways and was struggle so posting this here incase it can help anyone else.

```
<div id="yourDiv">
              <div class="row no-gutters">
                 <div class="col-auto">
                     <label>Starting Sp:</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col">
                            <input id="startingSp"/>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-auto">
                            <button>Go</button>
                 </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
  input, select {
        width: 100%;
  }
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0hr4m9y6/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="blah">
<div class="lineContainer">
        <select class="left">
            <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" id="search">

<input type="submit"  class="right" value="Search">

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lineContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
.lineContainer div {
    height: 30px
} 
.left {
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    border: none;
    padding: 2px 0;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

#search {
    border: none;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 2px 0;
    float: left;
}

.blah {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in `#text` you should let the width by a specific number, for example: 500px. Because in your CSS code, you did'nt set the width for whole page, so if `#text` has `width:100%;`, its almost change nothing!